# Dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, resx

I have a resource file I grab like this:

```
var rs = <somewhere>.FAQ.ResourceManager
     .GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
```

and I want to parse it into a dictionary of dictionaries but I can't figure out quite how.  this is what I'm trying:

```
var ret = rs.OfType<DictionaryEntry>()
  .Where(x => x.Key.ToString().StartsWith("Title"))
  .ToDictionary<string, Dictionary<String, string>>(
    k => k.Value.ToString(),
    v => rs.OfType<DictionaryEntry>()
      .Where(x => x.Key.ToString().StartsWith(v.Value.ToString().Replace("Title", "")))
      .ToDictionary<string, string>(
        key => key.Value,
        val => val.Value
      )
  );
```

so if I understand this correctly, `k` should refer to a DictionaryEntry and thus I should be able to dereference it like `k.Value` and to manufacture my dictionary in each of the outer dictionary's entries I do another query against the resource file, thus `key` and `val` should also be of type DictionaryEntry.

In referencing `val.Value` I get the error "Cannot choose method from method group.  Did you intend to invoke the method?" though that should be a property, not a method.

help?

p.s. as an explanation, my resource file looks sort of like this:

```
TitleUser:  User Questions
TitleCust:  Customer Questions 
User1: Why does something happen? Because… 
User2: How do I do this? Start by…
Cust1: Where can I find…?  It is located at… 
Cust2: Is there any…? yes, look for it…
```

which means I first get a list of sections (by looking for all keys that start with "Title") and for each I look for a list of questions

Comment: Side note: try to split your code into separate statements or better into separate functions with good names... You'll not be able to read that single line LINQ next day.

Comment: oh yeah, thanks for the negative rating on my post, whoever you are. really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the answer turns out to be that the compiler knows better as to the types involved.  leaving out the specifiers makes it work, though quite why my specifiers were wrong I don't yet get.

```
var ret = rs.OfType<DictionaryEntry>()
  .Where(x => x.Key.ToString().StartsWith("Title"))
  .ToDictionary(
    k => k.Value.ToString(),
    v => rs.OfType<DictionaryEntry>()
      .Where(x => x.Key.ToString().StartsWith(v.Key.ToString().Replace("Title", "")))
      .ToDictionary(
        x => x.Value.ToString().Split('?')[0] + "?",
        x => x.Value.ToString().Split('?')[1]
      )
  );
```

(I've made some changes to actually make it do what I intended for it to do).